# Invalid object name 'dbo.Tasks'. in Code First approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using code first approach to connect with database and tables but due to some issue enable/add migration command is not creating my tables so I created tables manually. Th application build successfully that means I assume the objDbContext get my table. The name of Table is Task in database.
Below is my code

```
eDbContext objDbContext = new eDbContext ();
 public List<TaskDetail> GetTasks(long eventId)
        {
            List<TaskDetail> listTask = new List<TaskDetail>();
            try {

                listTask = (from task in objDbContext.Tasks
                            where task.EventId==eventId
                            select new TaskDetail
                            {
                                Id = task.Id,
                                Title = task.Title,
                                Description = task.Description,
                                StartDate = task.StartDate,
                                EndDate = task.EndDate
                            }
                            ).ToList();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
            return listTask;

        }
```

Below is database context

```
 public class eDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: `throw ex` rewrites the stack trace; `throw` will do just fine. Side side note: Why `catch` just to `throw`?

Comment: basically you did everything wrong...

Comment: So Valkyriee, what did I wrong there. Please suggest me because I am new to code first.

Comment: @ChetuIndia what sergey said will fix your problem.

Comment: @ChetuIndia i assume your issue was solved. please accept the solution then.

Answer (score 2):

If you have similar problem (plural table names) for other entities, then you should remove `PluralizingTableNameConvention` (by default EF generates plural table names from entity type names). Add this code to your DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

If other tables have plural names, then you should just fix mapping for `Task` entity as @Valkyriee suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your DbContext Class should look like this:

```
public class eDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IebContext()
        : base("name=ConnectionStringName")
    {

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<eDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>("CatalogName"));

    }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TaskMap());
    }

}
```

For your Migration you can create a new class like:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<eDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        //know this might loss data while its true. 
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        ContextKey = "Path to your DbContext Class";
    }

    protected override void Seed(eDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

Now using this approach you can create your tables with EF code-first and change them later on. Note that I've added a Map Class for Tasks which means i am using fluent api for Mapping my entity:

```
public class TaskMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Task>
{
    public TaskMap ()
    {
        ToTable("Tasks");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```